# How to print data in struct that I've read from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, fstream

I am writing a program to keep track of a bookstore inventory (beginning code). One of the functions of this program is that it can print out the whole inventory in a more or less formatted output. I've gotten it to print out the contents with no spaces or whitespace.

I have the file reading into an array initialized as a struct:

```
struct Book //declare struct
{

int ISBN; //ISBN within struct

std::string Title; //Title within struct

std::string Author; //Author within struct

std::string Publisher; // Publisher within struct

int Quantity; //Quantity within struct

double Price; //price within struct

};
```

The contents of the .txt file get read into each memory allocation as their particular data type and then each of these gets printed out.

```
                                        /* READ CONTENTS OF INVENTORY*/

string readInventory(ifstream &readFile) //define readInventory, pass it a refrence to an infile
{
    const int ARRAY_size = 100;

string_book read_out_inventory[ARRAY_size];

ifstream inFile;

string stub = "\n\n***** COMPLETED: files read ******\n\n";
string buffer = " ";

inFile.open("inventory.txt");

if (!inFile.eof())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_size; ++i)
    {
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].ISBN;
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].Title;
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].Author;
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].Publisher;
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].Quantity;
        inFile >> read_out_inventory[i].Price;

    }
}

cout << setw(43) <<"The books are: \n\n" ;

for (int ARRAY_read = 0; ARRAY_read < ARRAY_size; ARRAY_read++)
{

    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].ISBN << endl;
    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].Title << endl;
    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].Author << endl;
    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].Publisher << endl;
    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].Quantity << endl;
    cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].Price << endl;

}

return stub;
```

}

The problem I'm running into (amidst other obvious ones) is that the output is :

```
0x7fff5fbfe250
0x7fff5fbfe268
0x7fff5fbfe280
0x7fff5fbfe288
0x7fff5fbfe290
0x7fff5fbfe298
0x7fff5fbfe2b0
0x7fff5fbfe2c8
0x7fff5fbfe2e0
0x7fff5fbfe2e8
0x7fff5fbfe2f0
0x7fff5fbfe2f8
0x7fff5fbfe310
0x7fff5fbfe328
0x7fff5fbfe340
0x7fff5fbfe348
0x7fff5fbfe350
0x7fff5fbfe358
0x7fff5fbfe370
0x7fff5fbfe388
0x7fff5fbfe3a0
0x7fff5fbfe3a8
0x7fff5fbfe3b0
0x7fff5fbfe3b8
0x7fff5fbfe3d0
0x7fff5fbfe3e8
0x7fff5fbfe400
0x7fff5fbfe408
0x7fff5fbfe410
...
```

I'm not even fully sure what my problem is so help would be greatly appreciated. I saw this question had been answered in another place but I didn't fully understand.

The .txt file looks like this:

```
20451
My First Book
Mark Lusk
Pearson Publishing
40
45.34
9780316
Brown Family
Mason Victor
Little Brown
36
105.99
1349877
Story of My Life
Norah M Jones
CreateSpace Independent Publishing Platform
20
18
1234567
The Big Book
Mypals Pennyweather
GreenThumb
4
13.23
```

Comment: I need to sort these books in the future too so having an array of structs would be useful for future proofing.

Comment: you are printing address of your struct members. Write `cout << read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read]` instead of `cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read]`. Just remove `&`.

Comment: Drop all the `&`s in `cout << ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code and file

> 1. While printing, you are printing address of every index using & operator.
> 2. You are using Array_size while printing the whole array, however your file has only 2-3 books.
> 3. There are white spaces in your text file and you are reading out of bound number of books.
> 4. Here is the modified code I wrote for you, that works for me :)

```
string readInventory() //define readInventory, pass it a refrence to an infile
{
const int ARRAY_size = 100;
int countBooksInFile=0;
Book inventory[ARRAY_size];
ifstream inFile;
string stub = "\n\n***** COMPLETED: files read ******\n\n";
inFile.open("inventory.txt");

if (!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile >> ws;
    inFile >> inventory[countBooksInFile].ISBN;
    inFile >> ws;
    getline(inFile,  inventory[countBooksInFile].Title);
    inFile >> ws;
    getline(inFile ,inventory[countBooksInFile].Author);
    inFile >> ws;
    getline(inFile, inventory[countBooksInFile].Publisher);
    inFile >> ws;
    inFile >> inventory[countBooksInFile].Quantity;
    inFile >> ws;
    inFile >> inventory[countBooksInFile].Price;
    countBooksInFile++;
}
cout << "Total Books: " << countBooksInFile<<endl;
cout << "The books are: \n";

for (int ARRAY_read = 0; ARRAY_read < countBooksInFile; ARRAY_read++)
{

    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].ISBN << endl;
    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].Title << endl;
    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].Author << endl;
    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].Publisher << endl;
    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].Quantity << endl;
    cout << inventory[ARRAY_read].Price << endl;

}

return stub;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I couldn't quite pinpoint all the mistakes and had been looking at it for too long.

Comment: @TBurns you're more than welcome my friend, kindly up vote and mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write a line of code like that one:

```
cout << &read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].ISBN << endl;
```

what you are doing is the following: you are asking to take an address (operator **&**) of an `ISBN` member of your struct and print it out. So what you see in your output are all those addresses.

If you just want to print the value (not an address) - don't take an address and output what you want "directly", like this:

```
cout << read_out_inventory[ARRAY_read].ISBN << endl;
```